Calculating Gradient of Slope
I have Slope (in degrees) raster data and I need to find out the gradient of slope. How to calculate gradient of slope in QGIS?

@user2856 Degrees.

Slope angle can be converted to gradient using the formula tan(slope).
The tan function requires radians not degrees so you need to convert slope degrees to radians using π/180.  Unfortunately the QGIS Raster Calculator doesn't have a pi() function or expression so you either need to hardcode pi as 3.141592 or use acos(-1):
E.g. for a layer called "Slope" in the map use:
tan("Slope@1" * 3.141592 / 180)


OR
tan("Slope@1" * acos(-1) / 180)



Thank you! I got it.

What should I do when someone answers my question?
